# How to read the body from a razor page? Process keeps hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I am sending data using this javascript code:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
xhr.open('POST', 'SavePage');
xhr.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', token);
xhr.send(payload);
```

Then in my SavePage.cshtml file i try to read directly from the body in many different ways, i have gotten the Content-Length and knows my data is 162 bytes long.

I have tried this simple example:

```
var buffer = new byte[1024];
var info = HttpContext.Request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, 5);
```

The code comes to the 2nd row and then is just hangs, in every way i try the code just hangs. If i try to read from the HttpContext.Request.Form it hangs as well.

When i check Chrome this is what's posted:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2uFNJ1OvmPRrGH1P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="main-content"

<p>
test
</p>
------WebKitFormBoundary2uFNJ1OvmPRrGH1P--
```

What am i missing here, should i not be able to just read from the body?
Or could it be that not the whole body has been sent but then why am i in the code already then?

Just FYI i am sending a part of a html text and just want to process it. Thought it might be easy to just read from the body and handle it myself. But although i am not new to c# i am a real newbie on core and asp and especially combined..

I have now tried to replace my cshtml file with a ApiController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SavePageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void SavePage([FromBody] string htmlString)
    {
        // done what was posted is in htmlString argument
    }
}
```

But then i get 400 Bad Request? I got that before i added the RequestVerificationToken but that is being sent? Not sure what is wrong then?

Comment: Why are you trying to access the HttpContext and request body directly? Why not create a proper action that accepts the data in its parameters? What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: Its mostly just html and some small parts in c#. So most of the code is plain html with partial views and for db stuff i only have one place for read which i do in the cshtml file directly and then the save part which dont work. Not sure how to setup an action. Dont i need to send a proper object then? I just receives this data from the javascript part which i have not written myself.

Comment: what do you want to send? plain html to the server, an object from a serialized form?

Comment: Plain html, the js variable payload will contain html-code that i just want to grab and save. But i cant even access it right now. Obviously i need to learn more about core and Asp.Net but thought that this simple project would help me get started but then i got stuck on this simple problem.. The js-code is shared with other projects and i would prefer not to change anything there.

Comment: Im sorry, found the problem. It was in the js code, when calling set header with "token". Copy paste error, token was not set in this method and then kestrel did not trust the verification and sent 400. Really bad error messages but my bad. Will try to work with the correct way you showed me and will accept that as the answer since this is probably the correct way to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send sting to controller action:

.net

```
[HttpPost]
public void SavePage([FromBody] string htmlString)
{
    // done what was posted is in htmlString argument
}
```

xhr java script exactly as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure if i understood correctly? I modified the question, i removed my cshtml file and added an ApiController to my project and inserted your code and added a breakpoint but it never gets called. I get a 400 Bad Request instead? As mentioned above i got that before when i had forgotten to add the RequestVerificationToken. But this is being sent? I would guess that i am missing something trivial...

Comment: check what is the correct route from to action, and use that when calling, it should be something like this: xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:300/api/SavePave/SavePage')

Comment: Starting to feel a bit stupid over here... I am pretty sure i am going to the right place, if i change the url it says 404 (Not found) so i think i am going to the correct place. My project is a Asp.Net Core 2.1 Razor pages, i just added a Api Controller to the project, do i need to do anything more. I will try to make a simple example and use your code and see if that works, maybe i have done something wrong in the setup.

Comment: try from postman to post html on the controller action see if is working or not

Comment: I tried before and still no luck. I made a simple sample if you (or anyone else) would have a minute over to see where i went wrong. I made a new project (ASP.NET Core Web Application) and cleared the Index page with a simple button that just post some data to a controller i added. I still get 400 Bad Request. https://expirebox.com/download/3d9f141153f555c3f451d31549ecf7f5.html

Comment: Ok not sure what happened? Now it works. Not sure what changed? Will try to figure it out if possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As mentioned above, the problem was me. Token was not set in this method, copy/paste error... However this seems to be the correct way to do it and i will try to convert my code into this instead. Since this is the way it should probably be done, i will set this as the answer. Thanks